# Fancy diagonal lines border around the container with CSS

Tags: css, border, containers

I am willing to achieve the fancy diagonal lines border effect around the container I want to style it via CSS I know by using before and after pseudo elements we can style different sort or borders around the container but here the situation is different as you can see in the image attached.

Many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `pseudo elements` for this purpose, you can try this:

CSS:

```
.checked {
    background-image:url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/old_map.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    position:relative;
}
.checked div {
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIHQn.jpg);
    padding:10px;
}
.checked img {
    max-width:100%;
}
div.checked:after {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: inherit;
    z-index:1;
}
div.checked:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: inherit;
    z-index:1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checked">
    <div>
        <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/fiverr.com/deliveries/45941/large/Cartoons_Caricatures_work_sample_from_pixzyl_1349432179.jpg?1349432179" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/180/

Comment: your solution is worth but it seems border width is not equal at the bottom, take a look on your demo fiddle.

Comment: It's because of the image dimension. If you set the dimension of your container in same ratio as that of the image, the border will be even

Comment: I see, btw do I have to make separate pattern image and style it with CSS class and use it on every container?

Comment: AS long as you want same pattern for image, you can save complete css in a class and use it on other elements, but if you want a different pattern then yes you need to change the image

Comment: Lastly, I am just wondering how the border is offsetting by leaving empty corners in top right and bottom left. It is because of before and after pseudo elements right?

Comment: yeah it's because of the top,left,bottom,right value of pseudo elements

Answer (score 0):

I think in the above image, image is used as a border. You can use any image as a border. Here is an eg. of how to use image as a border:

```
div {
-webkit-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari 3-5 */
-o-border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera 11-12 */
border-image:url(border.png) 30 30 round;
}
```

css syntax: border-image: source slice width outset repeat|initial|inherit;